# nodejs jsonwebtoken with PEM file: error "PEM_read_bio:no start line"

Tags: javascript, node.js, openssl, cryptography, json-web-token

I know there are a bunch of similar questions here but after hours of reading I cannot find a solution to mine. So:

I am trying to use [jwk-to-pem](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwk-to-pem) for signing a JSON web token using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken). I have previously achieved this but now the same code does not work. After calling `jwt.sign` with the generated `pem` I get `error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`.
I know that common reasons would include wrong linebreaks like `\r` or generally wrong format. I actually even dug through the core nodejs code and found [the line](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/73ae2d1895c2c0d1d4eeaddd284c58d776d2be87/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c#L707) throwing this error.

Countless adjustments and attempts brought no solution. Specifically:

- I made sure that all linebreaks are `\n`
- I tried different strings for the first and last line, e.g. `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` or `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`
- I made sure that the last line contains a `\n` as last character
- I tried to write the `pem` string to disk and re-reading it, using node's `fs`.
- I compared the `pem` file to several other files with several editors e.g. using `vi -b` or regex.
- I tried handing the raw file buffer with the `pem` content to `jwt.sign` as well as `pem.toString('utf8')` as well as *every* other string encouding supported by node
- I tried to generate a random `pem` file using linux tools and give that to `jwt.sign`. Specifically: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f jwtRS256.key` 
  `openssl rsa -in jwtRS256.key -pubout -outform PEM -out jwtRS256.pem`

What am I missing here? What possible causes I did not think of can this have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple explanation: I was by mistake using the public instead of the private key. The error thrown by openssl/crypto is very misleading.

Using a private pem/key the signing works as expected.